# Script for testing C# console Application and produce profiling results

Tags: c#, .net, scripting, mono

I have written a C# console application in which  I accept a set of inputs from user by `Console.ReadLine();`. I return the possible replacements  of one of the inputs in the set.These are returned as Lists. Now I want to test my application for about 100 set of input values and want to know how many replacements are possible for each input variable in the given set.I also want the profiling results for each run.

Is there a method i can do this without myself testing the code against 100 sets? I hope there is a way where i can list my input set in some file(a csv file probably) from where the input is redirected everytime.

I will be ok with using MONO in linux if there is a solution there.
Thanks :-)

Comment: have you tried [nunit](http://www.nunit.org/)?

Answer (score 0):

What you can consider doing is using the `Process` class.

```
var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = "consoleapp.exe",
    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
    CreateNoWindow = false,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    RedirectStandardInput = true
};

using (Process clconfigureclient = Process.Start(processInfo))
{
    // Write input to your application.
    clconfigureclient.StandardInput.WriteLine(value1);
    clconfigureclient.StandardInput.WriteLine(value1);
    clconfigureclient.WaitForExit();
}

output = cm.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
// Do checks on output.
```

Comment: Even if I use a for loop and vary my inputs ,how do i get the profiling results of each call of the .exe application

Comment: I do not know what sort of profiling you wish to be running. Just total time executed? You can use a stopwatch timer for that. Does your app record in the windows performance monitor? And so forth.